# Why do I need to specify `-o auto` for join's `-e` option to work?

Tags: gnu, join, coreutils

With the following two simple files:

`a.txt`

```
1 a
2 b
5 c
```

`b.txt`

```
2 x
4 y
5 z
```

The following command does not behave like expected:

```bsh
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 a.txt b.txt 
1 a
2 b x
4 y
5 c z
```

I would expect the option `-e 0` to fill up missing values with zeroes. However, the following does work:

```bsh
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o auto a.txt b.txt 
1 a 0
2 b x
4 0 y
5 c z
```

Reading documentation from `$ man join`, I see no connection between `-o` and `-e` that would make the above behaviour meaningful.
Instead, I find it misleading that a useless `-o auto` needs to be inserted into my command for `-e 0` to work..

Is there an explanation? Or should I file this as a bug to coreutils?

Comment: Since you tagged with `coreutils`, I assume this is about the GNU version of `join` (the one found on Linux systems), right? If not, please undo the tag edit I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this has been filed as a formal report [there](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=54625). The answer is that there *is* a connection between `-e` and `-o`, which is explained in the `info join` page. A patch has been released to also clarify it in the `man info` page.